Keyboard shortcut to switch context to Terminal in RStudio?
I'm aware of

ctrl + 1 to switch context to the script pane
ctrl + 2 to switch context to the console pane
opt + shift + r to switch to and refresh the terminal (found here).

But what I really want is the shortcut to switch to the terminal (without refreshing it).

Note: there's a similar sounding question here, but it's really asking how to switch between script pane and console (even though the question refers to it as the 'Terminal').

opt/alt + shift + m should do it.

@lotus brilliant, that's it! ty!
